# How to set DPI scale to 100% in windows 10 kiosk-mode?

Tags: windows, uwp, kiosk-mode

Is it possible some how, to change the DPI scaling setting in kiosk-mode Windows 10 LTSC ?

In the kiosk-mode windows 10,the UWP application is set up to 150%, so UI controls are really large.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say that in UWP apps, it is not possible to change the scale size of the system. My suggestion is that you might need to scale the controls in your app based on the system scale value to make your app looks better.

You could use the following code to get the current scale size:

```
    DisplayInformation information = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();

        var factor = information.ResolutionScale;
```

Then you could apply a transform for the controls in your app to make them look better. For example using the [ScaleTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.scaletransform?view=winrt-22621)